# How do I search all git repos in Azure Devops for a term?

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure Devops on premise with the version "AzureDevOpsServer_202306...".

I'm asking myself how to search all git repos in the source control for a term, for example to search for a class "Schoolbus" or a nuget package "CsvHelper".

Is there an easy way to do this?

Or do I really need to clone all the repos to my hard drive and then search for the relevant term?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to search the Git repos in Azure Devops for a term now. However, a colleague at work recommended the free addon "Code Search" by Microsoft for Azure Devops, which should solve this problem.
See: [Code Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search)